# Parsing a string at compile time

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to make the following code compile:

```
#include <string_view>

constexpr size_t get_member_count(const char * va)
{
    const char * p = va;        
    size_t count = 1;
    while (*p != 0)
    {
        if (*p++ == ',')
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

template <const char * va>
constexpr auto get_member_names()
{
    constexpr size_t count = get_member_count(va);
    static std::basic_string_view<char> v[count];
    //fill the array here
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr const char * mem_list = "a, b, c";
    constexpr auto v = get_member_names<mem_list>();
}
```

Both MSVC 2017 and GCC 9 do not compile 'get_member_names()' telling 'no matching overloaded function found' or 'no matching function for call' respectively.

Function get_member_count compiles and I can do:

```
constexpr size_t mem_count = get_member_count(mem_list);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [[temp.arg.nontype]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#arg.nontype-2):

> For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, or for each non-static data member of reference or pointer type in a non-type template-parameter of class type or subobject thereof, the reference or pointer value shall not refer to or be the address of (respectively):
>
> - [...]
> - a string literal ([lex.string]),
> - [...]

So this:

> ```
> constexpr const char * mem_list = "a, b, c";
> constexpr auto v = get_member_names<mem_list>();
> ```

Can't work. You have to make an array of static storage duration. Like so:

```
static const char mem_list[] = "a, b, c";
constexpr auto v = get_member_names<mem_list>();
```